# WPF WebBrowser with Javascript crashes Application

Tags: javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have to include a WebBrowser in our WPF-app to show data of a device (a camera). Using a standard browser (ie Firefox or IE) works just fine. Doing the same in WPF does give me some troubles.

First i got a *.js-error which i solved with this regestry entries:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

The WebBrowser is implemented like this:

```
<WebBrowser Source="http://192.168.1.2/" />
```

the site does open when i open the according View the first time. When i open the View a second time, the whole Application crashes without throwing any error.

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: can u find any error related to the clash in event viewer?